# Kafka ELK load CSV

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat

I log CSV value into Apache Kafka using filebeat.
I need to extract this value using Logstash (Apache Kafka have a JSON value) and then save it to elasticsearch.
My question is how I can configure my logstash to achieve this task.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [Logstash Kafka Input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html)?

Comment: yes, I need an example of the filter to extract the payload than put into elasticsearch

Comment: Can you share your existing logstash conf?

Comment: thanks, I had a blurred picture of how logstash work. the problem is solved

Comment: @Ali I am also facing the same issue. Can you please share your solution.